# Why .NET Core IMemoryCache allocates more memory than necessary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-core-webapi, in-memory

I'm working on .NET Core Web Api application and recently implemented `IMemoryCache` caching and `BackgroundService` to refresh the cache every hour. The cache expiration is 2hrs, so it should never go to the db during regular HTTP request. This is my cache class and refresh service:

```
public class FooCache : IFooCache
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly string _key = "Foo";
    private readonly int _durationInHours = 2;
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public FooCache(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public bool TryGetFoo(out List<FooOutput> values)
    {
        try
        {
            Semaphore.Wait();
            return _cache.TryGetValue(_key, out values);
        }
        finally
        {
            Semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public void SetFoo(List<FooOutput> values)
    {
        try
        {
            Semaphore.Wait();
            _cache.Set(_key, values, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(_durationInHours));
        }
        finally
        {
            Semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}

public class RefreshFooService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly IFooCache _fooCache;

    public RefreshFooService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IFooCache fooCache)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _fooCache = fooCache;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var fooData = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFooData>();
                var foo = await fooData.GetFoo();
                _fooCache.SetFoo(foo);
            }
            await Task.Delay(3600000, stoppingToken); // Refresh every hour
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how much of memory this object should take, but here's what I noticed: Without caching and `BackgroundService` the app uses ~200MB. With `BackgroundService` after first refresh, it takes 2.1GB of memory, after second refresh it takes ~3.5GB (sometimes I see 4GB) and it will stay at this level after following refreshes (assuming no API requests are coming).

I understand that for a brief moment the App stores old and new object in memory, right here:

```
var fooData = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFooData>();
var foo = await fooData.GetFoo();
_fooCache.SetFoo(foo);
```

... the new data is already in `foo` object, but `_fooCache` still has the old data.

But, shouldn't GC step in and free up the memory of `foo` object after it's assigned to cache?? Specially after few hours? What am I missing?

Comment: Hard to say, without more information. Have you verified that only one instance of FooCache is being injected? Have you checked to see what happens if you use simple Memoization instead of MemoryCache? Have you tried invoking garbage collection after your refresh service replaces the Foo value? Have you inspected a memory dump to see what objects seem to be consuming memory?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I didn't invoke GC after the refresh, I thought I didn't have to, since `foo` variable is out of scope when the process exits `using` statement, so I believe GC should pick it up automatically. I just tied calling `GC.Collect()` after `_fooCache.SetFoo(foo)` and it worked! I did reduce memory by 1.4GB. How come GC didn't to it automatically?

Comment: @AdamWojnar because GC has not been invoked. Depending on GC type it has some different conditions [to start collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#conditions-for-a-garbage-collection).

Comment: @GuruStron Interesting, so although it is advised not to call `GC.Collect()` explicitly, in this case it would be advisable to actually call it

Comment: @AdamWojnar actually it depends. You can look into some GC settings: [GCHeapHardLimit](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/running-with-server-gc-in-a-small-container-scenario-part-1-hard-limit-for-the-gc-heap/) for example.

Comment: Yeah, there's lots of dark magic involved with the garbage collector, and you're usually better off letting the framework decide when to kick off GC. It could be that your machine just happens to have enough available memory that there's no point invoking garbage collection until memory usage gets higher. But if you're trying to track down a memory leak, invoking GC directly is a useful diagnostics tool.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior so in other words it's good to run `GC.Collect` if I truly want to know how much memory my app really needs (while developing). But in production I don't have to run `GC.Collect` because higher memory consumption doesn't matter and if it gets too big, GC will Collect it itself. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right to me.